# How to remove server info header from web api core 3.1 response which is hosted as azure web app?

Tags: azure, .net-core

I have an azure web api developed in .net core 3.1. Request and response working fine. I am trying to remove server header from api response but no successes so far.

[image]

```
 Tried below things,

option 1) Added in programe.cs

 static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) => Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>{webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(serverOptions =>
            {
                serverOptions.AddServerHeader = false;
            }).UseStartup<Startup>();                    
            });

option 2) Added in Configure method of startup.cs 
       app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            context.Response.OnStarting(() =>
                {
                    int responseStatusCode = context.Response.StatusCode;
                    if (responseStatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.Created)
                    {
                        IHeaderDictionary headers = context.Response.Headers;
                        StringValues locationHeaderValue = string.Empty;
                        if (headers.TryGetValue("Server", out locationHeaderValue))
                        {
                        context.Response.Headers.Remove("Server");
                        }
                    }
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                    });

option 3) Added in Configure method of startup.cs 
 app.Use(async (context, next) =>  
            {  
                context.Response.Headers.Remove("Server");
                await next();  
            }

Either of these did not worked in my case. Am i missing anything here?
Please provide your suggestions.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Kestrel:
Try setting Kestrel options like below snippet in Program.cs. The Kestrel Server header gets added too late in the request pipeline. Therefore removing it via the web.config or via middleware is not possible.
Note: Below I used UseKestrel instead of ConfigureKestrel.

```
       public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                    webBuilder.UseKestrel(options => options.AddServerHeader = false)
                });
```

For IIS: You need to set in web.config like below:

```
<configuration> 
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering removeServerHeader="true" />
    </security>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Tried your suggestion, ended up with error " HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure". but tried with web.config and it worked fine.

Comment: Thanks for trying. My bad. It seems you are into IIS integrated (just noticed later in your screenshot) so the kestrel option would cause failure. Web.config is the way to go. Updated the answer.